# When to use/omit "of" between two words?

Tags: prepositions

Here is the sentence:

> Let the users spend more time playing this game and make the users come back often after their first-day of gameplay.

When I try to omit the "of" like this, the grammarly app tells me not to do so.

> Let the users spend more time playing this game and make the users come back often after their first-day gameplay.

Well, when I read the sentence, I feel that omitting the "of" is all good. May I ask when two words need a preposition between them?

Comment: Think about it this way: do you want the users to come back after the day, or after the gameplay?  It might seem like the same thing, but the original sentence says "I want them to come back after the first day (in which they played the game) and your change says "I want them to come back after their gameplay" and "first day" is simply modifying "gameplay".

Comment: So both sentences are legal but are delivering different meanings?

Comment: They're both grammatically correct, yes.  I think "first day of gameplay" makes a lot more sense, because you're saying that you want them to come back another day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rule for 'when two words need a preposition between them'.

I don't know why *first-day* is hyphenated here, but *a day of [something]* means a day spent doing that, or one when something was happening all the time (*a day of rain*). So *their first day of gameplay* is the first day they spent playing the game. You could also say *their first day's gameplay.* It doesn't sound idiomatic without either *of* or the possessive.